# Applying a window function to a frame in librosa

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, librosa

I am currently working on an ASR system, and I've forgotten to apply a window function to each frame. I am extracting, which could be the cause to why I am receiving bad results. But is that possible in `librosa`?

I can't find this option in librosa documentation.

I need to apply a hamming window on to each frame, which are extracted as such.

```
   for fp in file_paths:
        y,sr = librosa.load(fp,sr=16000)
        X = librosa.util.frame(y, frame_length=400, hop_length=160)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Librosa employs scipy.signal:

```
window = scipy.signal.hann(win_length, sym=False)

# Reshape so that the window can be broadcast
window = window.reshape((-1, 1))

windowed = fft_window * X
```

[Here](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/_modules/librosa/core/spectrum.html#stft) you can see how it is done inside librosa.

But why not to use `librosa.stft` or `librosa.mfcc`? It will do everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Where do you actually apply the window in the frame ?
About doing it in mfcc computation in librosa,  i wanted to train an NN for computing them which is why i needed to proper preprocessing..

Comment: Windowing is performed before Fourier transform to avoid spectral leakage.